# JQM vs AngularUI

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, angular-ui

I am pretty new to hybrid app development and am trying to experiment with jquery mobile, angularui and ionic. However, most discussions online suggest that jqm is slow and ionic/angularui are preferred over jquery mobile. So am trying to understand what kind of applications would be best developed in JQM?

Also I came across this post - https://cdnify.com/blog/top-10-mobile-frameworks-performance/. It seems to be comparing JQM and phonegap. My understanding was that JQM/MAUI/Ionic are UI frameworks and even if you use them you would still need cordova to generate executable for android/ios. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right JQM/ionic/ecc.. are ui framework, you need phonegap or similar for generate native application.

Choose JQM, angular, ionic or react is your choice depending on your taste or what you need to do.
In my expirience JQM is very rigid i prefer angular+bootsrap or ionic